# More than 100 % Training Accuracy at end of each epoch

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, pytorch, computer-vision

I am training a Siamese network with Binary Cross Entropy Loss and calculating classification accuracy.
I have more than 100 % training accuracy at the end of each epoch. I am not able to fix this.

Following is the screenshot of the issue. (Please look at Epoch 1/20 : Accuracy : 116.98)
[image]

Following is the code snippet of train epoch and fit function:

```
def fit(train_loader, val_loader, model, loss_fn, optimizer, scheduler, n_epochs, cuda, log_interval, metrics,
        start_epoch=0, message=None) -> object:
    """
    Loaders, model, loss function and metrics should work together for a given task,
    i.e. The model should be able to process data output of loaders,
    loss function should process target output of loaders and outputs from the model

    Examples: Classification: batch loader, classification model, NLL loss, accuracy metric
    Siamese network: Siamese loader, siamese model, contrastive loss
    Online triplet learning: batch loader, embedding model, online triplet loss
    """
    for epoch in range(0, start_epoch):
        scheduler.step()
    #log_data['epoch'] = []
    #log_data['train_losses'] = []

    for epoch in range(start_epoch, n_epochs):
        #log_data['epoch'].append(epoch)
        scheduler.step()

        # Train stage
        train_loss, metrics = train_epoch(train_loader, model, loss_fn, optimizer, cuda, log_interval, metrics)
        #log_data['train_loss'].append(train_loss)

        message = 'Epoch: {}/{}. Train set: Average loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch + 1, n_epochs, train_loss)
        for metric in metrics:
            message += '\t{}: {}'.format(metric.name(), metric.value())

        val_loss, metrics = test_epoch(val_loader, model, loss_fn, cuda, metrics, log_interval)
        val_loss /= len(val_loader)

        message += '\nEpoch: {}/{}. Validation set: Average loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch + 1, n_epochs,
                                                                                 val_loss)
        for metric in metrics:
            message += '\t{}: {}'.format(metric.name(), metric.value())

        print(message)


def train_epoch(train_loader, model, loss_fn, optimizer, cuda, log_interval, metrics):
    for metric in metrics:
        metric.reset()

    model.train()
    losses = []
    total_loss = 0


    for batch_idx, ((x0, x1), y) in enumerate(train_loader):

        x0, x1, y_true = x0.cpu(), x1.cpu(), y.cpu()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output1, output2 = model(x0, x1)

        p_dist = torch.nn.PairwiseDistance(keepdim=True)

        dy = p_dist(output1, output2)
        dy = torch.nan_to_num(dy)
        y_true = torch.nan_to_num(y_true)

        '''2 lines indicated the normalization of dy to 0 and 1 by dividing it with max value'''

        maximum_dy = torch.max(dy)
        maximum_dy = torch.nan_to_num(maximum_dy)
        dy = dy/maximum_dy

        maximum_y_true = torch.max(y_true)
        maximum_y_true = torch.nan_to_num(maximum_y_true)

        y_true = y_true/maximum_y_true

        dy = torch.squeeze(dy, 1)
 
        input_dy = torch.empty(dy.size(0), 2)
        input_dy[:, 0] = 1 - dy
        input_dy[:, 1] = dy
      

        y_true_2 = torch.zeros(dy.size(0), 2)
        y_true_2[range(y_true_2.shape[0]), y_true.long()] = 1

  
        m = nn.Sigmoid()
        loss = loss_fn(m(input_dy), y_true_2)

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        losses.append(loss.item())
        total_loss += loss.item()

        input_dy_metric = torch.round(input_dy)
        for metric in metrics:
            metric(input_dy_metric, y_true_2)
        for metric in metrics:
            metric.total = (batch_idx+1)*y_true_2.shape[0]

        if batch_idx % log_interval == 0:
            message = 'Train: [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                batch_idx, len(train_loader),
                100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader), np.mean(losses))
            for metric in metrics:
                message += '\t{}: {}'.format(metric.name(), metric.value())

            print(message)
            losses = []

    total_loss /= (batch_idx + 1)
    return total_loss, metrics
```

Following is the Accuracy meric definition :

```
class Metric:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, outputs, target, loss):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def reset(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def value(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def name(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Binary_accuracy(Metric):
    """
    Works with classification model
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.correct = 0
        self.total = 0

    def __call__(self, input_dy_metric, y_true_2):

        self.correct += (input_dy_metric == y_true_2).sum().float()/2

    def reset(self):
        self.correct = 0
        self.total = 0

    def value(self):
        return 100 * float(self.correct) / self.total
        #print(len(self.correct))
        #print(self.total)
    def name(self):
        return 'Accuracy'
```

Thank you in advance.
Any help is most appreciated!

Comment: Why is this tagged keras?

Comment: More importantly, you are not updating the total variable so accuracy will not be correct.

Comment: It's a suggestion that you use Functional Api for these tasks and not make things overly complex.

Comment: Can you mark the changes that you feel should be carried out here?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @AbhishekPrajapat. But I do not want to change the approach completely. I just need mirror changes here so that it works, but not able to catch the solution.

Comment: check your total and correct values at the time of printing so you can see if one is exceeding its expected/maximum value